# Выбор среды программирования

Tags: c++, графика, directx, аудио

Как создать программу, которая позволит работать со звуком в прямом потоке (через микрофон) и в записи. А именно:
1. Анализировать звуковые колебания, деля звуковую дорожку на десятые доли секунды.
2. Показывать в интерфейсе программы соответствующий график.
Какие средства программирования тут следует использовать?
Рационально ли будет интегрировать в C++ Excel для работы с графиками и DirectX для работы с аудио?

Comment: при данных условиях Вам подходит Visual Studio. Он есть в express версии, которая бесплатная. На крайний случай, можно использовать C++Builder. Как по мне, то в билдере можно сделать все достаточно быстро.

Comment: Путь разработки лежит у вас либо в среде Visual Studio (C#, C++), либо в RAD Studio XE (Delphi, Builder c++). Это два наиболее мощных пакета, в которых можно работать с DirectX, с Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использовать Excel для графиков - это из пушки по воробьям, если, конечно, мы с Вами под построением графиков понимаем одно и то же.
Судя по всему, Вам потребуется реализовать пользовательский интерфейс. Раз так, для реализации пользовательского интерфейса есть очень удобные кросс-платформенные библиотеки, такие как Qt и wxWidgets. Мой личный выбор когда-то пал на wxwidgets, и я ни разу не пожалел, но это вопрос предпочтений.
Оба указанных набора библиотек содержат в себе множество инструментов для работы с экраном, в том числе и инструменты для построения графиков. Кроме того, никто не помешает Вам, используя средства этих библиотек, просто рисовать графики самому. Для того, чтобы научиться делать это с нуля, Вам понадобится не более пары часов. Даже это решение будет лучше, чем решение через Excel по следующим параметрам:

- переносимость
- скорость работы
- привязка к наличию Microsoft Office на машине, который, насколько я помню, не бесплатный.

Что касается работы с DirectX, то тут надо просто брать directx sdk. Насколько корректно использовать DirectX для работы со звуком - не знаю, но гугл подтверждает, что выбор хороший.

Насчет предлагаемой IDE, в принципе, любая. Если выберете Qt, то, наверное, Qt Creator. Я бы рекомендовал MinGW с последней версией gcc (если работаете под Windows), CodeBlocks в качестве IDE и сборку этим компилятором wxWidgets и directx.
Если возьмете MinGW тут: http://nuwen.net/mingw.html , то там в комплекте с самыми современными средствами разработки будет и SDL для работы со звуком. Останется только, следуя инструкциям, собрать wxWidgets.

Если параллельно будете собирать проект последней майкрософтной Visual Studio, будет некоторая гарантия того, что Ваш код - хороший (признаком чего и будет служить то, что он успешно собирается gcc и msvc-12.0/13.0).